# replace elements of vector by condition

Tags: matlab

I have got a vector `a` and a vecor `b`. And a have bound vectors `lb` and `ub`. I want to replace: `a[i] = b[i]` if `lb[i]<b[i]<ub[i]`. How should I do it without loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
M = lb < b & b < ub;
a(M) = b(M);
```